# How to create an array that will adhere to certain Union type without having to copy myself?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type, and for consistency reasons, I need to declare it once and at some point make a check if an array includes an element in the NameUnion type.

```js
type NameUnion =
  // Home && login
  | 'email'
  | 'newEmail'
  | 'password'
  | 'passwordConfirm'
  | 'deleteAccountPassword'

if(['email','newEmail','password','passwordConfirm','deleteAccountPassword'].includes(name)){
// do somthing
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgan1m) meet your needs? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (You might also want to [edit] so the code is a [mre] where only the issue you're describing exists; right now `name` is not declared so I can't test that part)

Comment: @jcalz the issue is I don't want to keep writing the names I want one singleton scr for them... the real type has 25 strings this one is reduced for illustration.

Comment: Okay, and my suggestion only has you write the names once.  Did you look at it?  If you have a problem with it can you explain exactly what the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

In this example, `NameUnion` is the type and `nameArray` is an array of that type. You can use this array in your includes check. The function `doSomething` takes a parameter of type `NameUnion` and checks if it is included in the `nameArray`.

**This is the approach you should be taking**:

```
type NameUnion =
  | 'email'
  | 'newEmail'
  | 'password'
  | 'passwordConfirm'
  | 'deleteAccountPassword';

const nameArray: NameUnion[] = ['email', 'newEmail', 'password', 'passwordConfirm', 'deleteAccountPassword'];

function doSomething(name: NameUnion): void {
  if(nameArray.includes(name)){
    // Do something here
    console.log(`name is in the NameUnion: ${name}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`name is NOT in the NameUnion: ${name}`);
  }
}

// Testing
doSomething('email');  // This should print "name is in the NameUnion: email"
doSomething('other');  // This should print "name is NOT in the NameUnion: other"
```